# How to add external svg file in the html and can that file accessible in javascript

Tags: jquery, html, svg, wiki

I wanted to add external SVG file (based on XML) into HTML page and the SVG loaded into the HTML page with the help of the `<iframe>`, `<object>`, `<img>`, and `<embed>` tags, but when I went to access the elements of the SVG in the javascript, it's not working. I can't access the internal element of any the above.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of code? for the JS part for instance?